What is the idiomatic way to make a generic type optional?
Context
I have a library, which lets you users define a schema, and returns custom response types based their definition. Here’s a minimum example:
interface Item {
  id: string;
}

interface CardinalityDef {
  [objectType: string]: 'one' | 'many'
}

class Schema<Cardinality extends CardinalityDef> {
  constructor(public cardinality: Cardinality) {}
}

type ResponseOf<
  S extends Schema<any>, 
  K extends keyof S['cardinality']
> = S['cardinality'][K] extends 'one'
  ? Item
  : Item[];

class DB<S extends Schema<any>>{ 
  query<ObjectType extends keyof S['cardinality']>(objectType: ObjectType): ResponseOf<S, ObjectType> { 
    return 1 as any;
  }
}

function init<S extends Schema<any>>(schema: S): DB<S> {
  return 1 as any;
}

Now I can define a schema, and get response types as I expect:
const schema = new Schema({posts: 'many', author: 'one'})
const db = init(schema);
// This is correctly typed at Item[]
const postsResponse = db.query('posts');
// This is correctly typed as Item
const authorResponse = db.query('author');

Playground Link
Goal: Make schema optional
I want to make it so a user does not have to provide a schema.
const db = init(); // no schema provided

If no schema is provided, all query responses should return Item[]:
const postsResponse: Item[] = db.query('posts');
const authorResponse: Item[] = db.query('author');

Option 1: IsAny
I can make the schema argument optional:
function init<S extends Schema<any>>(schema?: S): DB<S> {
  return 1 as any;
}

Then update the ResponseOf type like so:
type IsAny<T> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? true : never;
type ResponseOf<
  S extends Schema<any>, 
  K extends keyof S['cardinality']
> = IsAny<S['cardinality']> extends true
  ? Item[] 
  : S['cardinality'][K] extends 'one' 
    ? Item 
    : Item[];

And now it will work:
const dbWithoutSchema = init();
const postsResponseWithoutSchema = dbWithoutSchema.query('posts'); // types as Item[]
const authorResponseWithoutSchema = dbWithoutSchema.query('author'); // types as Item[]

Playground Link
But, I am not sure if this is idiomatic. Mainly:

It feels surprising that db is typed as Schema<any>.  It really has no schema at all.
It feels weird that I have to explicitly check for any in ResponseOf. It's like I am fighting with typescript.

Option 2: Schema | undefined
I could also be explicit about the undefined case, like so:
function init<S extends Schema<any> | undefined>(schema?: S): DB<S> {
  return 1 as any;
}

Playground Link
But, this doesn’t feel right either. The downsides I see:

I have to thread through | undefined all throughout the system
It’s weird that in the case where I don’t provide a schema, typescript doesn’t refine S to strictly undefined

Question
Which approach is more idiomatic in typescript? Would you suggest a different approach, for allowing an optional schema?
I am leaning towards defaulting the type to Schema, and doing the IsAny check explicitly. My main reasoning is that this would a) remove the need to thread through | undefined everywhere, and b) make the type refine when no schema is provided.
All thoughts really welcome!

Yes, the idiomatic approach is probably to use a default generic type parameter, as shown in this playground link.  If you find yourself writing IsAny something has probably gone wrong. If you don't pass in schema then S has no place from which to infer, it's not inferred as undefined unless you pass in undefined explicitly. Does that fully address the question? If so, I'll write an answer; if not, what's missing?

That definitely addresses the question, thank you! Please do write the answer

If you want a type parameter to fall back to something if it cannot be inferred, you can give it a default type argument:
function init<
    S extends Schema<any> = Schema<{ [k: string]: 'many' }>
>(schema?: S): DB<S> {
    return 1 as any;
}

Here, if you call init() and TypeScript cannot infer S from it because you have not passed in a schema argument, TypeScript will fall back to the default of Schema<{ [k: string]: 'many' }>, where the type argument for Schema has a string index signature whose type is "many".  That means if you call init() with no argument, TypeScript will treat that is if you called init(schema) where schema's cardinality property treats all possible properties as being of type "many", thereby mapping every possible key to Item[]:
const dbWithoutSchema = init();
const postsResponseWithoutSchema = dbWithoutSchema.query('posts');
//    ^? const postsResponseWithoutSchema: Item[]
const authorResponseWithoutSchema = dbWithoutSchema.query('author');
//    ^? const authorResponseWithoutSchema: Item[]
const randomResponseWithoutSchema = dbWithoutSchema.query('randomCrud');
// ^? const randomResponseWithoutSchema: Item[]

It allows you to call query() with any property key you'd like. When you do pass in an argument, it behaves as before, where the type argument is inferred as the type of that argument, and returns Item or Item[] depending on the key, and it only lets you pass in known keys:
const schema = new Schema({ posts: 'many', author: 'one' })
const db = init(schema);
const postsResponse = db.query('posts');
//    ^? const postsResponse: Item[]
const authorResponse = db.query('author');
//    ^? const authorResponse: Item
db.query('randomCrud') // error,
//      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// '"randomCrud"' is not assignable to '"posts" | "author"'


Using default generic type arguments is the idiomatic approach to this sort of thing. Your other approaches work or can be made to work, although you really do not want to try to detect any, and while undefined might be a reasonable thing to add to the domain of the type parameter, TypeScript won't actually infer undefined if you leave out the argument, since the equivalence of init(undefined) and init() isn't reflected in type inference. So you'd still need to set it as the default, yielding something like
function init<
    S extends Schema<any> | undefined = undefined
>(schema?: S): S extends undefined ? DB<Schema<{ [k: string]: 'many' }>> : DB<S> {
    return 1 as any;
}

but that's more complicated, and I'd only recommend that if you expect people to call init(undefined) explicitly (and approximately nobody does that in practice).
Playground link to code

I don't like defaults for type parameters, as TypeScript sometimes (invisibly) falls back to them when it cannot otherwise infer the correct (and expected) type for some other reason; also they're easy to forget when using the type (e.g. in a function that should have been generic but was not made generic because the declaration works fine with the default type). Wouldn't a more idiomatic approach be to overload the init function?

‍♂️ I guess the problem with "idiomatic" is that it depends on who you're asking (unless you do a big survey of real world code). Overloads are fine, but they have their own issues, so it depends on what you want to do. Default type arguments are meant for this sort of thing, but if you don't like the behavior you shouldn't use it. Not sure how best to address this in the answer. Maybe a separate answer describing the overload solution would work too?

Yeah I guess the default type parameter isn't as bad in generic functions as it is in generic types - I just had some bad experiences with those. I've posted an answer now as you suggested. It's not on me to decide which is better.

Thanks for the discussion team. I ended up going with the default type param, mainly for intellsense. Right now when you have overloads, VSCode just chooses the first overload, and writes (+N overloads). I find it looks a bit confusing, so sticking with the default param. I understand this is more of a preference though

An alternative to the default for the type parameter in @jcalz' answer is to use an overload declaration for the function:
function init(): DB<Schema<{ [k: string]: 'many' }>>;
function init<S extends Schema<any>>(schema: S): DB<S>;
function init(schema?: Schema<any>) {
  return 1 as any;
}

